# Constructing polynomials with rational critical values

Tags: polynomials, elementary-functions

I have poked around the forum, and haven't been able to find an answer to the following question:

Given $n$ integral points $(x_i, y_i)$ with distinct $x_i$, is it possible to construct a polynomial $P(x)$ with rational coefficients such that

- all (not necessarily distinct) critical points of $P(x)$ are rational points, and
- all $n$ of the provided integer points are on the polynomial $(P(x_i) = y_i)$ and are not critical points $(P'(x_i) \neq 0)$.

If so, how would one go about constructing $P$?

---

What if we are additionally given an integer $d > n > 0$, and told $P(x)$ must be degree $d$?

Comment: Please include work/ideas you have tried.

Comment: I did not see a way to proceed with Lagrange interpolation, as you need to both select fixed points ahead of time and insure all derivatives satisfy the necessary conditions, which was difficult in my attempts. 

In the degree $d$ case, you can fix the $n$ required points, then handpick at most $d-n$ rational critical points before you determine the polynomial, and saw no way to do this in a way that ensures the remaining critical points are rational.